# How to Copy a Config From TFS to Staging Site using MS Build 2017

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I want to copy my Config File Directly from TFS to Another Server where my site is hosted. How can i do it using TFS Build 2017. Which Task i need to add for this and what arguments i need to specify if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) task, and you need to specify the source path, remote machine IP addresses, the username and password that login the remote machine, and the destination folder.